# Fazer cópia de uma linha por vez do arquivo de origem, para os arquivos destinos

Tags: linux, script, bash, shell, sh

Surgiu uma nova necessidade acompanhada de uma boa e nova pergunta que até então não encontrei nada parecido na internet - *Copiar uma única linha por vez, para um único arquivo diferente*.

**Exemplo a cada nova linha a ser copiada:**

```
total=10

linha=`cat Arquivo_de_origem`

for i in `seq $total`
    echo "$linha" > /home/$USER/$i
done
```

O arquivo de origem contém mais de 10 linhas, mas apenas preciso pegar dez, por isso dou o limite na variável `total=10`

Isso fará o `for` percorrer **10x** determinado por `seq`, interando sobre `i`

O `echo` seguido da variável `linha` estabelece linha-por-linha

Dai arquivos de destino estão sendo criado em números ordinais - *1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...*

Então teríamos de copiar 1º linha para 1º arquivo, copiar 2º linha para 2º arquivo e assim vai.

> **Concluíndo** - fazer cópia de um **nome** para um  **único arquivo**.

Sei que terei de usar um **incremento** e tals, mas não sei como.

Comment: Barbadinha, vou escrever o script e logo posto aqui pra vc. Essas o conteúdo dessas linhas tem espaço entre as palavras? Me de um exemplo de linha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diego, desculpe a demora. mas estive offline esses dias. Segue minha resposta.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Limite que será usado no for
limit=10
# Diretório de destino dos arquivos
dir_dest="/home/mkt/tmp/"
# Arquivo de origem
arq_orig="/home/mkt/tmp/tst"
# Conteúdo do arquivo
arq=$(cat $arq_orig)
for (( i = 0; i < $limit; i++ )); do
    # Parametro de linha que será usado com o sed
    linha=$[i + 1]
    # Finalmente criando o arquivo tendo seu conteúdo cada
    # cada linha do arquivo de origem
    echo "$arq" | sed -n "$linha"p > $dir_dest/$i.txt
done
```

Usei o **sed** pois acredito ser a melhor opção para a ação que deseja, pois ele pega todo conteúdo da linha, independente de ter ou não caracteres especiais.
Conteúdo do arquivo que usei foi baseado na sugestão do **Tom Melo** mas com espaços em determinadas linhas.

```
~#cat tst 
Rogério : Amélia
Cleiton:Bruna
Mauro : Carla
Diego:Denise
Maicon : Emiliane
Delvair:Fátima
José:Graça
Marcos:Helena
Neto : Irene
Tiago:Júlia
```

Resultado:

```
~# ls -1
0.txt
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
4.txt
5.txt
6.txt
7.txt
8.txt
9.txt
```

Conteúdo de cada arquivo criado pelo script:

```
~# cat 0.txt
Rogério : Amélia
~# cat 1.txt
Cleiton:Bruna
~# cat 2.txt
Mauro : Carla
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Usando `for` fica assim:

```
#!/bin/sh
NUM=0
MAX=10
# Caso tenha Nome e Sobrenome por exemplo: Ana Paula
IFS=$'\n'
for LINHA in $(cat lista-casais.txt)
do
    if [ $NUM -lt $MAX ]; then
        M=$(echo $LINHA | cut -d ':' -f1)
        F=$(echo $LINHA | cut -d ':' -f2)
        echo -ne "Masculino:$M\nFeminino:$F" > /home/$USER/noivos/$NUM
        NUM=$((NUM+1))
    fi
done
```

#### Referência

- [IFS](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html)

Answer (score 1):

Partindo do ponto que se arquivo tem o seguinte formato:

```
Rogério:Amélia
Cleiton:Bruna
Mauro:Carla
Diego:Denise
Maicon:Emiliane
Delvair:Fátima
José:Graça
Marcos:Helena
Neto:Irene
Tiago:Júlia
```

Podemos utilizar o **head** + **awk**:

```
head -n 10 casais.txt  | awk -F ":" '{print "Masculino:"$1"\nFeminino:"$2"" > ""NR".txt"}'
```

Ou então uma versão simplificada apenas com **awk**:

```
awk -F ":" '{if(NR<=10) print "Masculino:"$1"\nFeminino:"$2"" > ""NR".txt"}' casais.txt
```

Basta você adaptar o script pra salvar no diretório desejado.

Answer (score 0):

Fiz com laço `while`, deixo aqui como registro para futura consulta. Veja:

## bourne shell

```
#!/bin/sh

num=0

cat lista-casais.txt | while read LINHA
do

  M=$(echo $LINHA | cut -d ':' -f1)
  F=$(echo $LINHA | cut -d ':' -f2)

if [ $num -lt 10 ]
then
    echo -ne "Masculino:$M\nFeminino:$F" > /home/$USER/noivos/$num
    num=$[num + 1]
fi

  let num=$[num + 1]

done &>/dev/null
```

**Pequena lista de amostra pra realizar teste:**

```
Rogério:Amélia
Cleiton:Bruna
Mauro:Carla
Diego:Denise
Maicon:Emiliane
Delvair:Fátima
José:Graça
Marcos:Helena
Neto:Irene
Tiago:Júlia
```

Comment: Vc quer usar um **loop** ok, mas coloque um **break**,**exit** no seu **if**. Suponhamos que seu arquivo tenha 1000 linhas, teu **loop** vai pegar as primeiras 10, e o script continuará rodando ate fazer as 1000 linhas.

Comment: `if [ $num -lt 10 ]; then echo -ne "Masculino:$M\nFeminino:$F" > /home/$USER/noivos/$num; num=$[num + 1]; else break; fi`